# Is This Post Or GET API?

Tags: api, post, get, retrofit2

Ok here is the api i got to upload data.

http://xxxxxxxxxxhiddenxxx.asmx/Ins_comp?name=nick&desc=tototo&no=1234567890&img_data=sgdyugt347trf34gf34g7rfg347d&uid=1&subject=Changeit

It is returning when tried with get

[
{
"result": "success"
}
]

When i send uid as "user" i get response

Input string was not in a correct format.

I need to upload image i converted it to base64 string but it says 'URL too long'. I compressed it and the image size in jped is 80 kb still same response.
I  new to this and after watching mamy tutorial all uses POST request so is this a POST api i am just writing it wrong way? Or what because simply type this api and select POST in postman get response 500

Comment: If it's a POST request, try placing the parameters in the body rather than the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it is post working with get as well.